# How do I get type parameter from type with type parameter, inside scala macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

I have a type (that, in this case, represents return type of a method), and it is of the form `List[Int]` (for example).

I know that the type carries that information, because `toString` results in the proper value, but how can I extract that type? I tried `.typeSymbol`, but that loses all type information altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TypeRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types%24TypeRefExtractor) extractor:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
// or in a macro "c.universe._"

val tpe = weakTypeOf[List[Int]]

// extract type parameters
val TypeRef(_,_, tps) = tpe

// tps has type List[Type]
println(tps.head) // Int
```