# TypeTags/Reflection - If I have a Type object, can I get its parameter Type?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

To simplify my scenario,
I have a Type object that is a Some[String] or Some[Int] or None.
Am I able to take that Type object and somehow get the parameter Type into another object?

Eg

```
scala>  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val tt = typeTag[Some[String]]
tt: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Some[String]] = TypeTag[scala.Some[String]]

scala> val tpe = tt.tpe
tpe: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.Some[String]
```

So there is your Type of Some[String].
How do I get the parameter type out of there into a Type object?

Comment: and possibly also [How do I get type parameter from type with type parameter, inside scala macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166911/how-do-i-get-type-parameter-from-type-with-type-parameter-inside-scala-macro).

Comment: macro is compile time not runtime reflection

Comment: @Senia I need the parameter of the the typeArgument.

Comment: yes, but the type API is completely identical, that's the point. Anyway, the answer in @senia's link will get you the type `String` given the type of `Some[String]`, which is I think what you need?

Comment: Okay - thanks - I'll try it out. The reflection api is pretty tricky to navigate I find... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Question marked as duplicate is not really answered and does not appear to get the type of the typeArg (parameter). In the answer you can see it still returns List[X] and not list

Comment: @JasonG hum, do you want `Some` or `String` out of `Some[String]`? see my answer.

Comment: Looking for String - I'll have another look - maybe I missed something

Comment: Ya you're right!! Sorry - I missed that thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166911/how-do-i-get-type-parameter-from-type-with-type-parameter-inside-scala-macro), you can use the [`TypeRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeRefExtractor) extractor:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

val tpe = typeOf[Some[String]] // same as typeTag[Some[String]].tpe

// extract type parameters
val TypeRef(_,_, tps) = tpe
// tps has type List[Type]

val innerType = tps.head // <-- here is your type
// innerType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne - sorry for the confusion. The reflection API isn't very easy to navigate.