# Scala Def Macros - How do I get the parameterized type member of a symbol?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, parameterized-types

I'm trying to get the parameterized type of a member on a symbol in a MACRO context.  I only have a symbol available (can't use weakTypeOf[List[Blah]]) because I am iterating over a bunch of classes.

```
val meWantArg = classSymbol.member("paramList": TermName).typeSignature
```

returns...

```
=> List[IWantThis]
```

How do I get IWantThis Type object???

I've tried:

```
meWantArg.typeSymbol.asType.typeParams //returns List(type A)
```

I've tried extraction:

```
TypeRef(_,_,args) = meWantArg //returns ()
```

Keep in mind, I am using the 2.10.2 macro plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding type parameters via reflection in Scala 2.10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842729/finding-type-parameters-via-reflection-in-scala-2-10)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get type parameter from type with type parameter, inside scala macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166911/how-do-i-get-type-parameter-from-type-with-type-parameter-inside-scala-macro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing from `=> IWantThis` that `paramList` is not a `val` but an arity-0 method without parentheses:

```
def paramList: List[IWantThis] = ???
```

If so, the member is a method type, and you have to get the return type of the method *before* extracting arguments from it:

```
val meWantArg = classSymbol.member("paramList": TermName).asMethod.returnType
val TypeRef(_,_,args) = meWantArg
```